# sed - how to remove everything but a defined pattern?

Tags: sed

I have to remove everything but 1, 2, or 3 digits (0-9, or 10-99, or 100) preceding **%** (I don't want to see the %, though) from another command's output and pipe it forward to another command. I know that

```
sed -n '/%/p'
```

will show only the line(s) containing **%**, but that's not what I want. How can I get rid of the rest of the unwanted text and leave only these numbers to then pipe them to another command?

Comment: are there multiple % values on each line, or just one % per line (plus other stuff). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter there is just one % per line (plus other stuff).

Comment: Coud you give us some examples of input and respective expeced output?

Comment: If you every time that need to sed, same me , can use the [Sed ref](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Answer (score 29):

If you're not completely tied to sed, this is exactly what `grep -o` does:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}%'
```

Comment: Great, but I don't want to see the %

Comment: If you have GNU grep, there is a `--perl-regexp` option, so you can do this to get the number before the percent: `grep -Po '\d{1,3}(?=%)'`

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: I have misunderstood the OP and posted an invalid answer. I changed it to an answer that, I believe, would solve the problem in the more general scenario.

For a file such as the one below:

```
$ cat input
abc
123%
123
abc%
this is 456% and nothing more
456
```

Use `sed  -n -E 's/(^|.*[^0-9])([0-9]{1,3})%.*/\2/p' input`

```
$  sed  -n -E 's/(^|.*[^0-9])([0-9]{1,3})%.*/\2/p' input
123
456
```

The `-n` flag makes sed to suppress automatic output of the lines. Then, we use the `-E` flag which will allow us to use extended regular expressions. (In GNU sed, the flag is not `-E` but instead is `-r`).

Now comes the `s///` command. The group `(^|.*[^0-9])` matchs either a beginning of line (`^`) or a series of zero or more chars (`.*`) ending in a non-digit char (`[^0-9]`). 
`[0-9]\{1,3\}` just matches one to three digits and is bound to a group (by the `(` and `)` group delimiters) if the group is preceded by `(^|.*[^0-9])` and followed by `%`. Then `.*` matches everything before and after this pattern. After this, we replace everything by the second group (`([0-9]{1,3})`) using the backreference `\2`. Since we passed `-n` to sed, nothing would be printed but we passed the `p` flag to the `s///` command. The result is that *if the replacement is executed* then the resulted line is printed. Note the `p` is a *flag* of `s///`, *not* the `p` command, because it comes just after the last `/`.

Comment: `Then .* matches everything before and after this pattern`. Why `before`?

Comment: If I remove the curly braces (result: one digit), can I then remove the `-E`?

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)%.*/\1/'` captures the digits in a group and because the pattern matches everything (the leading and trailing `.*`) it all gets discarded.

(my pattern matches any number of digits since `sed` regular expressions don't support handy shortcuts like `[0-9]{1,3}` that you see in perlre and others so I elected to keep it simple to illustrate the principle you cared about)

Edit: to fix quoting and replace leading `.*` with `[^0-9]*` to avoid the greedy match consuming the numbers.  Once again more straightforward with perlre where you can use a non-greedy `.?*`

Comment: Acually, at least my version of `sed` (GNU sed 4.2.1) accepts `{m,n}` expressions. Even without the `-r` extended regexp flag.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my shot:

```
sed "/^[0-9]{1,3}%$/ bnum; d; :num s/%//"
```

If the line is 1-3 digits followed by a %, it removes the %-sign. Otherwise, it removes the entire line. So, for input such as

```
adsf
50
52%
 1
 12%
test%
1234%
%%%
85%
bye
```

It yields

```
52
85
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` instead of `sed`.

```
$ cat file
one two 100% three
10% four 1% five

$ awk '{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
   if ($i ~/%$/) { print $i+0} }
  'file
100
10
1
```

For each field, check to see if there is `%` sign at the end. If yes, print the number. ($i+0 means to convert to integer). Minimal Regular expression used.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "/[0-9]\{1,2\}%/ s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)%.*/\1/p
/100%/ s/.*/100/p
"
```

the 100% is to be extracted because otherwise number of kind 987% (or 123% if filtered on 1 at 1st position) are also send to output